# SharpMap: Creating and editing geometry

Tags: c#, sharpmap, geoapi, nettopologysuite

I´m working in a project using sharpmap on this we're displaying information, but is necessary create and edit too. I have experience with presenting information but i need  some advices with creating and editing.

I am working with 1.1.0 version of Sharpmap and all complementary tools, GeoAPI, NetTopologySuite, so on, with C#.

I'm working my geometry elements such as points in the database and in my app I convert them to polygons for the viewing and lines (linestring) for creation.

From a list of coordinates I am drawing a geometry and this complete element need move, rotate and flip, how I can realize this?

All help is wellcome, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your tried using GeometryFactory to create a polygon?

ref https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21318/how-to-convert-lines-to-polygons-using-nettopologysuite

Comment: Please provide more information and not only a link

Comment: Yes, i am using GeometryFactory for create a polygon, But besides that I perform modification operations on that polygon, cut, split, create new vertices, delete vertices, scale. These operations either by entering the coordinates or by pointing with the mouse on the map.